# F# accumulating sequence of random numbers

Tags: f#

I want to create a sequence of numbers where each number is the sum of all the numbers gone before it plus a random number.

I tried to do it like this:

```
let random = new System.Random()
let addRandom  = 
    seq{let rec stepRandom acc =          
           let step = random.Next(0,10)
               yield! acc+step     //-----wont accept this
               stepRandom (acc+step) 
        stepRandom 0 }
```

The problem is it won't accept the yield inside a recursive function.

I can see a solution with a mutable value for the accumulation, but how could this problem be solved in an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you align the sequence expression with the inner function, then it becomes a natural recursive function definition. Additionally, going by your description, you want to yield the accumulator (or the new sum), not the new random int.

```
let random = new System.Random()
let addRandom  = 
    let rec stepRandom acc = seq{          
        let step = random.Next(0,10)
        yield acc
        yield! stepRandom (acc + step) }
    stepRandom 0
```

Answer (score 5):

How about a different approach, using the lovely `unfold` function:

```
let random = new System.Random()
let r() = random.Next(0, 10)
let s = Seq.unfold (fun acc -> Some(acc, acc+r())) (r())
```

Unfold creates a sequence from an *initial state* (in this case the first random number - second argument) and a *generator function* (first argument) that takes the previous state and produces (1) a new state (in this case the sum of the previous state plus the random) and (2) a new element in the sequence (the previous state).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [Seq.initInfinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx) with [Seq.scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340364.aspx):

```
let rand = System.Random()
let s = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> rand.Next(0, 10)) 
     |> Seq.scan (+) 0
     |> Seq.skip 1
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it as well. However, I would pipe it to `Seq.skip 1` afterwards, to get rid of the leading `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
seq { let rand = System.Random()
      while true do
        yield rand.Next(0, 10) }
|> Seq.scan (+) 0
```